# Ignore Time From DateTime Cell In Excel

Tags: vba, excel, datetime, excel-2013

I am using VBA to capture the date input into a cell.  The problem I have is that if the cell is blank the VBA reads it as 12:00:00 AM so my ISDATE() function in VBA sees it as a date, but the code blows up since it is not an actual date.  What VBA syntax can actaully check to verify the cell contains a DATE?

This is my current syntax

```
Sub IsDate()
Dim d1 As Date

d1 = CDate(Range("A1").Value)

If IsEmpty(Range("A1")) = False Then
  If IsDate(d1) = True Then
        'Continue
  End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsEmpty(Range("A1"))` will give you inconsistent results use `Range("A1").Value <> ""`.

Don't name your subroutines after built in VBA methods For example `Sub IsDate()` will overwrite the VBA method and wreak havoc.

[image]

```
Sub TestIsDate()

    Dim d1 As Date
    If Range("A1").Value <> "" And IsDate(Range("A1").Value) Then
        d1 = CDate(Range("A1").Value)
    End If

End Sub
```